# Connect to svn master when outside firewall, connect to svn slave when inside

Tags: svn, replication, master-slave

Here is the planned setup.

1. Subversion master outside the corporate firewall, as a cloud instance.
2. one svn slave replicated with the cloud svn master, but is inside corporate firewall (office network).
3. Now people when inside office, connect to svn slave for updates and commits directed at slave are written through proxy forward to the cloud svn master. (Standard svn master-slave setup)
4. Users checkout a repository from inside office, so the url used will point to the slave repo.
5. User makes some changes to the files, not checked in yet.

Now problem is

1. what happens to users when they work from home (no vpn) and want to commit or update ? The checked out project(repo) points to slave, which is not accessible from outside office.
2. Will the user has to change the url manually and make it point to svn master in cloud and then do the updates/commits when outside office network? And change back to point to svn slave when inside office network ?
3. Is there a way to automate this, or make it transparent to the end user? So when user works from home it points to svn master in cloud and when inside office it points to svn slave ?

Comment: Assuming you have separate DNS servers for external and internal clients you could create an DNS entry for the same name pointing to different servers inside and outside.

Comment: Separate dns, :-) no that is not an option.

Comment: Such a [split horizon DNS set-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS) is quite common in companies. Why should someone on the Internet be able to query dns names of corporate internal devices?

Comment: So u mean to say, the cloud svn is named named master.domain.com and so is internal one master.domain.com (but this is the slave svn). So internal dns server resolves this to internal ip. And the public dns (thus would be say from godaddy), which is used by users when they are outside, and that resolves to the public ip of master svn in cloud. But one question, what shud I configure in the "write through proxy" config of slave svn, shud I directly use ip address of master svn in cloud instead of master.domain.com ? (Coz thus would resolve to itself from inside the network)